# Query to use intermediate Value

Tags: hana

Hi I am trying to write a query to use the intermediate output.

I have a table with PROD_DATE, PRICE as columns, When I give the below query in HANA the query executes as expected.

```
select round(days_between( MIN(PROD_DATE) , MAX(PROD_DATE))/365) as yea,    
SUM(PRICE) as totalRevenue from AAA;
```

If I want to use the `yea` and `totalRevenue` columns calculated previously like below:

```
select round(days_between( MIN(PROD_DATE) , MAX(PROD_DATE))/365) as yea,    
SUM(PRICE) as totalRevenue, totalRevenue/yea as perc from AAA;
```

it gives me an error

> ERROR is INVALID COLUMN NAME totalRevenue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct.  You cannot use a value assigned in a `SELECT` again in the `SELECT`.  You can repeat the expressions or use a subquery:

```
SELECT t.*, totalRevenue/yea
FROM (select round(days_between( MIN(PROD_DATE) , MAX(PROD_DATE))/365) as yea, 
             SUM(PRICE) as totalRevenue, totalRevenue/yea as perc
      from AAA
     ) t
```